# Cannot install docker on fresh Ubuntu 17 Server, docker is missing permissions to operate in /var/lib/docker

Tags: server, apt, permissions, 17.04, docker

I followed [this guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) to install docker on a new Ubuntu 17 server. However, I cannot get docker to run.

Installing docker via `sudo apt-get install docker-ce` yields:

```
...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service → /lib/systemd/system/docker.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/docker.socket → /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket.
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-10-16 08:57:52 UTC; 8ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 7325 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 7325 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CPU: 49ms
```

Checking `sudo journalctl -u docker` gives

```
    Oct 16 08:57:51 vm1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed to reset devices.list: Operation not permitted
Oct 16 08:57:51 vm1 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Oct 16 08:57:51 vm1 dockerd[7325]: time="2017-10-16T08:57:51.743612657Z" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 7335"
Oct 16 08:57:52 vm1 dockerd[7325]: time="2017-10-16T08:57:52.816490740Z" level=warning msg="failed to rename /var/lib/docker/tmp for background deletion: rename /var/lib/docker/tmp /var/lib/docker/tmp-old
Oct 16 08:57:52 vm1 dockerd[7325]: time="2017-10-16T08:57:52.816839404Z" level=error msg="Could not check if docker-default AppArmor profile was loaded: open /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles: permis
Oct 16 08:57:52 vm1 dockerd[7325]: Error starting daemon: couldn't create plugin manager: error setting plugin manager root to private: permission denied
Oct 16 08:57:52 vm1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 16 08:57:52 vm1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Oct 16 08:57:52 vm1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 16 08:57:52 vm1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 16 08:57:53 vm1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 16 08:57:53 vm1 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Oct 16 08:57:53 vm1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed to reset devices.list: Operation not permitted
Oct 16 08:57:53 vm1 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Oct 16 08:57:53 vm1 dockerd[7369]: time="2017-10-16T08:57:53.224145403Z" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 7390"
Oct 16 08:57:54 vm1 dockerd[7369]: time="2017-10-16T08:57:54.241186206Z" level=error msg="Could not check if docker-default AppArmor profile was loaded: open /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles: permis
Oct 16 08:57:54 vm1 dockerd[7369]: Error starting daemon: couldn't create plugin manager: error setting plugin manager root to private: permission denied
```

What I find weird is the line `failed to rename /var/lib/docker/tmp` as if docker has no permissions to work in its image directory `/var/lib/docker`.

Any idea what is wrong or how to fix this? Thanks!

## Edit

I was able to install an older version of docker: `docker-ce_17.03.2~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb`.

But now running an image like `sudo docker run hello-world` fails with

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
5b0f327be733: Extracting [==================================================>]    974 B/974 B
docker: failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: permission denied.
```

Comment: Same to me in CentOs 7.4. Any idea which not be downgrade?

Comment: I used `sudo snap install docker` in a 17.10 VM, and got `sudo docker run hello-world` running fine.  I also tried the longer instructions to pull from the upstream archive that you linked, and it worked fine as well.  I'd suggest trying again as perhaps things have improved since then.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a AppArmor profile issue. Recheck unfiltered `journalctl`/`dmesg` for apparmor messages.

You can find more debug instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/).